# Problem with adding different numbers to a register in Verilog (Vivado)

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm currently in a university class learning about digital system design in Verilog using Vivado. My final project is an American football scoreboard. I'm working on implementing the score feature (for both teams), and I'm having an issue with adding 6, 3, 2, and 1 point to a total points register.

Each point input is linked to a switch. I want it to where if I move one switch, it adds 6 points to an output (for a touchdown). Another switch adds 3 points to the total. So on for 2 points and 1 point. This is the code I've currently got. Right now, it only adds the 6 points to the register successfully (only adding it once per switch on). The others make my seven-segment display jump around, looking like its adding very fast whenever the 3, 2, and 1 point switches are on.

The score tops out at 99 since I'm using two 7-segment displays per team. I've got a binary to decimal module and a seven segment converter module, and both of those are working. There's also a masterReset input, which resets the score to zero. The reset input works.

```
module teamAPoints(
input masterReset,
input teamATouchdown,
input teamAFieldGoal,
input teamA2PtConv,
input teamAExtraPoint,
output reg [6:0] teamAScore
);


always @ (posedge masterReset or posedge teamATouchdown or posedge teamAFieldGoal or posedge teamA2PtConv or posedge teamAExtraPoint) begin
    if (masterReset) begin
        teamAScore <= 0;
    end
    else if (teamAExtraPoint) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 1;
    end
    else if (teamA2PtConv) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 2;
    end
    else if (teamAFieldGoal) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 3;
    end
    else if (teamATouchdown) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 6;
    end
end
endmodule
```

I hope I explained this well enough. I've also tried turning this into a finite state machine, but had no luck. I get that I'm describing hardware on an FPGA, and I'm very used to standard programming languages like Java and C. I bet that's the source of my error. Any and all help/explanations is appreciated.

Comment: I'm using the 2 point conversion input as the safety input as well since they're both 2 points. I've only got so many switches on my board. I should rename it

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a register to be able to store anything. Currently you are using wires hence the score ain't getting properly updated. You would need an additional clock signal which is needed to design sequential circuits. Try below code.

```
   module teamAPoints(
     input masterReset,
     input teamATouchdown,
     input teamAFieldGoal,
     input teamA2PtConv,
     input teamAExtraPoint,
     input clk,     //Added a clock signal
     output reg [6:0] teamAScore
     );


   always @ (posedge clk or posedge masterReset) begin
      if (masterReset) begin
         teamAScore <= 0;
       end
      else if (teamAExtraPoint) begin
         teamAScore <= teamAScore + 1;
       end
     else if (teamA2PtConv) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 2;
     end
     else if (teamAFieldGoal) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 3;
     end
     else if (teamATouchdown) begin
        teamAScore <= teamAScore + 6;
     end
  end
 endmodule
```

In you test bench add below snippets

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps  //change the timescale as per your need.
module tb();

reg clk;  //Declaration

localparam CLK_PERIOD = 10; //Add your clock period here to adjust the frequency

initial
begin
 clk = 1'd0;
end

always
 #CLK_PERIOD/2 : clk = ~clk;
```